# Terraform, ElasticSearch: This site can’t be reached

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-elasticsearch, cloudposse

I provisioned Elasticsearch. I got URL outputs of "domain_endpoint",  "domain_hostname", "kibana_endpoint" and "kibana_hostname". But, I cannot hit any of these URLS. I got, "This site can’t be reached". What do I miss? Below is the code:
main.tf:

```
module "elasticsearch" {
  source                  = "git::https://github.com/cloudposse/terraform-aws-elasticsearch.git?ref=tags/0.24.1"
  security_groups                = [data.terraform_remote_state.vpc.outputs.default_security_group_id]
  vpc_id                         = data.terraform_remote_state.vpc.outputs.vpc_id
  zone_awareness_enabled         = var.zone_awareness_enabled
  subnet_ids                     = slice(data.terraform_remote_state.vpc.outputs.private_subnets, 0, 2)
  elasticsearch_version          = var.elasticsearch_version
  instance_type                  = var.instance_type
  instance_count                 = var.instance_count
  encrypt_at_rest_enabled        = var.encrypt_at_rest_enabled
  dedicated_master_enabled       = var.dedicated_master_enabled
  create_iam_service_linked_role = var.create_iam_service_linked_role
  kibana_subdomain_name          = var.kibana_subdomain_name
  ebs_volume_size                = var.ebs_volume_size
  dns_zone_id                    = var.dns_zone_id
  kibana_hostname_enabled        = var.kibana_hostname_enabled
  domain_hostname_enabled        = var.domain_hostname_enabled
  advanced_options = {
    "rest.action.multi.allow_explicit_index" = "true"
  }
  context = module.this.context
}
```

terraform.tfvars:

```
enabled = true
region = "us-west-2"
namespace = "dev"
stage = "abcd"
name = "abcd"
instance_type = "m5.xlarge.elasticsearch"
elasticsearch_version = "7.7"
instance_count = 2
zone_awareness_enabled = true
encrypt_at_rest_enabled = false
dedicated_master_enabled = false
elasticsearch_subdomain_name = "abcd"
kibana_subdomain_name = "abcd"
ebs_volume_size = 250
create_iam_service_linked_role = false
dns_zone_id = "Z08006012KJUIEOPDLIUQ"
kibana_hostname_enabled = true
domain_hostname_enabled = true
```

Comment: How do you access it? You set it into private subnets, so you can't access your ES over the internet.

Comment: Per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-vpc.html#es-migrating-public-to-vpc, About Access Policies on VPC Domains.
Placing your Amazon ES domain within a VPC provides an inherent, strong layer of security. When you create a domain with public access, the endpoint takes the following form. How to create a domain with public access? Does it mean place ES into public subnets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are placing your ES domain in VPC in private subnets. It does not matter if its public or private subent, public access does not apply here. From the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-vpc.html#es-vpc-security):

> To perform even basic GET requests, your computer **must be able to connect to the VPC**. This connection often takes the form of a VPN, managed network, or proxy server.

Even if you place it in public subnet, it will not be accessible over internet. A popular solution to this issue is through **ssh tunnel** which is also described in AWS docs for ES:

- [Testing VPC Domains](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-vpc.html#es-vpc-security)